# How to ensure minimum delay at setTimeout() in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Question is straight forward.

e.g. i need to execute some code after at least 50 ms (not 49.8 ms).

```
// min-timeout.spec.js
const util = require('util');
const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');

const wait = util.promisify(setTimeout);

it.only('setTimeout() minimum delay', async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const start = performance.now();
    await wait(50);
    const time = performance.now() - start;
    console.log('time:', time);
  }
});
```

Output:

```
time: 51.01539999991655
time: 50.70590000227094
time: 50.79270000010729
time: 50.22399900108576
time: 49.343199998140335
time: 50.81929999962449
time: 49.999699000269175
time: 49.83229999989271
time: 50.78200000151992
time: 50.010999999940395
```

Why sometimes execution time is less than 50 ms? Is it system dependent? How to ensure minimum delay at setTimeout() in Node.js?

System info:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.285]
node v8.11.2
```

Comment: Hmm, it's weird it executes after *less* time than the delay specified. You usually see the opposite - where it takes more time, as there are other pending calls before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is specific to how timers are scheduled in Node.js within event loop. It's possible that asynchronously scheduled `setTimeout` will be triggered one millisecond earlier, while average delay will be equal to specified delay or higher.

In order for this behaviour to be compensated, it could be:

```
const wait = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ++delay));
```

In case a delay is needed to test asynchronous code, timer mocks can be used to fast-forward a timer.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that this is rather due to `performance.now()` inaccuracy.

Comment: Interesting. Therefore, currently there is no point to use performance.now() instead of Date.now()?

Comment: This is a guesswork. `performance.now` in Node isn't the same as in browsers, which is mentioned in the article. You would get same result with other Node time measurements (which are quite precise, btw).

Comment: @mcMerphy Yup, `process.hrtime()` might be more accurate, but I'm unable to find the nodejs spectre report so I cannot confirm that yet...

Comment: You can check that it the result is the same with other measurement methods in Node versions released before SPECTRE.

Comment: @estus I'm currently afk so I can't, but as you did I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: But how should i write tests then? `expect(time).to.be.at.least(49)`?

Comment: @McMerphy What are you writing tests for? What's your case? Seems like you have XY problem.

Comment: @estus Yes, it should be another question.
Anyway, setTimeout() guarantee that it will execute function only after provided delay, but there is no way to measure actual delay with sufficient precision to check it?

Comment: @McMerphy It's not a problem with measurements but with how timers are scheduled in Node. In my experience they the difference isn't bigger than 1ms on the smaller side, so it would be safe to compensate a timeout with 1ms if it's crucial for it to not be shorter. I can hardly imagine a scenario where this would be an issue. Two 50ms timeouts will still perform in correct order, so there would be no race conditions. As for your testing, I believe this should be done in more appropriate way. If you're testing code that uses setTimeout, you could use timer mocks.